# Making network log-in persistent in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Is there any generic way to make my connection to a wireless network persistent in windows 7? i can connect to the network, but i have to type in my name and password every time i boot. How can i make it automatic?

i have one of [these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833315091) connected to the computer, with the program it came with running. However, the 7 version is somewhat different from the xp version, and i cant do the same thing as i did in xp with 7

Comment: This seems to be a missing feature in the program provided with the connectore. The best solution is to contact the manufacturer and ask them to add that feature. This does not seem to be a Windows 7 issue.